# How can we access secure httpsonly cookie in next js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, httpcookie

we are calling https://demo.com/auth/session in next js application

backend team set the response cookie as secure HttpOnly cookie

```
const session = await (
  await fetch(
   `https://demo.com/auth/session`,
    requestOptions
      )).json();

console.log("cookies",ctx?.req?.headers?.cookie);
```

**backend cookies code**

```
Set-Cookie: id=a3fWa; Expires=Thu, 21 Oct 2021 07:28:00 GMT; Secure; HttpOnly
```

how can we access secure HttpOnly cookie in next js application

Comment: Where in your Next.js app are you calling that endpoint, client-side or server-side?

Comment: calling end point at server-side..

Answer (score 0):

You cant access HttpOnly cookie by using client side JavaScript. It is intended to be like that because of security(to prevent some type of attacks).

Please use it as a reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: That's true, but I am accessing this HTTPOnly cookie in the server side. Can i access this cookie in the server side (NextJS)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but perhaps yes.

inside your getServerSideProps you can do:

```
let mycookie = getCookie("cookieName", {ctx.req, ctx.res});
```

getCookie is a method from package "cookies-next" and ctx is the context object passed in the getServerSideProps automatically by nextjs. getCookie() will access the req headers and get the cookie by its name. Again I am not sure whether this will work or not. :)

Edit: Well, accessing httpOnly cookie, is a very bad Idea actually :)